# modified version of reader/writer in Operating system concept

Tags: operating-system

As you know in reader-writer problem in operating system concept, the structure reader and writer is as follow:

[image]

now imagine that we want n writer can write simultanously if no reader is reading and reverse:

I did it as the following:

[image]

but I am not sure about that ? am I missing anything or if the whole pseudocode seems correct?

Comment: In the future, please post all code as text, not images.

Comment: Sorry for that and thanks for bringing it up:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is absolutely correct but I don't know if it is reasonable to write at the same time